# Dynamixel AX-12 help

Tags: ros, dynamixel, ax12

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.

I'm trying to work with ROS and AX-12 servos on an eeePC. I have the USB2Dynamixel dongle and i can read the states of the 3 servos I have connected by using the ax12_driver_core package, but cant find and way of actually controlling the servos to move. The robotis package has launch files but for the RS series of servos. Any help would be wonderful.

Thank you in advanced.
Chris Paton

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10885/dynamixel-ax-12-help/) by [Aether robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/950/aether-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2011-08-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-08-12**:
Hi Chris--you might want to check out the new dynamixel_motor stack (http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_motor) which I believe will be replacing ax12_driver_core going forward.  (Though Anton can correct me if I am wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both `ax12_controller_core` and `ax12_driver_core` packages are deprecated, you should use [dynamixel_motor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_motor) stack instead. Try working through the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials) and see if they help. If you run into any problems, just update the question and we'll try try to resolve them.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2